# Iteration that removes the first row and adds the next row in the dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have created this sample dataframe of 50 rows.

```
pass_subset <- structure(list(player_name = c("Nemanja Maksimovic", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", 
"Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Djené Dakonam Ortega", 
"Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", 
"Nemanja Maksimovic", "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
"Djené Dakonam Ortega", "Nemanja Maksimovic", "Allan Romeo Nyom", 
"Jorge Molina Vidal", "Allan Romeo Nyom", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", 
"Oghenekaro Etebo", "Djené Dakonam Ortega", "Oghenekaro Etebo", 
"Jorge Molina Vidal", "Mathías Olivera Miramontes", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
"Jorge Molina Vidal", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
"Jorge Molina Vidal", "Mathías Olivera Miramontes", "Mathías Olivera Miramontes", 
"Nemanja Maksimovic", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi", 
"Jorge Molina Vidal", "Mathías Olivera Miramontes", "Oghenekaro Etebo", 
"Nemanja Maksimovic", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
"Djené Dakonam Ortega", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Oghenekaro Etebo", 
"Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Nemanja Maksimovic", "Djené Dakonam Ortega", 
"Djené Dakonam Ortega", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Djené Dakonam Ortega", 
"Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", 
"Jorge Molina Vidal"), receive_player = c("Jaime Mata Arnaiz", 
"Jorge Molina Vidal", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", 
"David Soria Solís", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Nemanja Maksimovic", 
"Jorge Molina Vidal", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Jorge Molina Vidal", 
"Jorge Molina Vidal", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Jorge Molina Vidal", 
"Nemanja Maksimovic", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Oghenekaro Etebo", 
"Djené Dakonam Ortega", "David Soria Solís", "David Soria Solís", 
"Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Jorge Molina Vidal", 
"Mathías Olivera Miramontes", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Jorge Molina Vidal", 
"Mathías Olivera Miramontes", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Nemanja Maksimovic", 
"Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Jorge Molina Vidal", 
"Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Oghenekaro Etebo", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", 
"Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", 
"David Soria Solís", "Oghenekaro Etebo", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", 
"Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi", "David Soria Solís", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", 
"Mathías Olivera Miramontes", "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
"Jorge Molina Vidal", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
"Nemanja Maksimovic"), type_name = c("pass", "pass", "pass", 
"pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
"pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
"pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
"pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
"pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
"pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass"), no_passes = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50)), row.names = c(6L, 
8L, 10L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 25L, 26L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 
40L, 42L, 44L, 46L, 49L, 50L, 53L, 55L, 57L, 60L, 67L, 69L, 71L, 
74L, 76L, 78L, 79L, 81L, 87L, 89L, 91L, 93L, 95L, 96L, 98L, 100L, 
102L, 108L, 110L, 112L, 116L, 121L, 122L, 124L, 126L, 131L), class = "data.frame")
```

### OUTPUT

```
                    player_name              receive_player type_name no_passes
6            Nemanja Maksimovic           Jaime Mata Arnaiz      pass         1
8             Jaime Mata Arnaiz          Jorge Molina Vidal      pass         2
10        Marc Cucurella Saseta           Jaime Mata Arnaiz      pass         3
15           Jorge Molina Vidal Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      pass         4
17         Djené Dakonam Ortega           David Soria Solís      pass         5
19  Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi       Marc Cucurella Saseta      pass         6
25  Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa          Nemanja Maksimovic      pass         7
26           Nemanja Maksimovic          Jorge Molina Vidal      pass         8
29           Jorge Molina Vidal       Marc Cucurella Saseta      pass         9
31        Marc Cucurella Saseta          Jorge Molina Vidal      pass        10
33         Djené Dakonam Ortega          Jorge Molina Vidal      pass        11
34           Nemanja Maksimovic           Jaime Mata Arnaiz      pass        12
35             Allan Romeo Nyom          Jorge Molina Vidal      pass        13
37           Jorge Molina Vidal          Nemanja Maksimovic      pass        14
40             Allan Romeo Nyom Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      pass        15
42  Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa            Oghenekaro Etebo      pass        16
44             Oghenekaro Etebo        Djené Dakonam Ortega      pass        17
46         Djené Dakonam Ortega           David Soria Solís      pass        18
49             Oghenekaro Etebo           David Soria Solís      pass        19
50           Jorge Molina Vidal           Jaime Mata Arnaiz      pass        20
53   Mathías Olivera Miramontes       Marc Cucurella Saseta      pass        21
55        Marc Cucurella Saseta          Jorge Molina Vidal      pass        22
57           Jorge Molina Vidal  Mathías Olivera Miramontes      pass        23
60        Marc Cucurella Saseta           Jaime Mata Arnaiz      pass        24
67        Marc Cucurella Saseta          Jorge Molina Vidal      pass        25
69           Jorge Molina Vidal  Mathías Olivera Miramontes      pass        26
71   Mathías Olivera Miramontes       Marc Cucurella Saseta      pass        27
74   Mathías Olivera Miramontes          Nemanja Maksimovic      pass        28
76           Nemanja Maksimovic Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      pass        29
78  Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa          Jorge Molina Vidal      pass        30
79  Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi          Jorge Molina Vidal      pass        31
81           Jorge Molina Vidal Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      pass        32
87   Mathías Olivera Miramontes            Oghenekaro Etebo      pass        33
89             Oghenekaro Etebo           Jaime Mata Arnaiz      pass        34
91           Nemanja Maksimovic           Jaime Mata Arnaiz      pass        35
93            Jaime Mata Arnaiz       Marc Cucurella Saseta      pass        36
95        Marc Cucurella Saseta           Jaime Mata Arnaiz      pass        37
96         Djené Dakonam Ortega           David Soria Solís      pass        38
98  Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa            Oghenekaro Etebo      pass        39
100            Oghenekaro Etebo Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      pass        40
102 Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi      pass        41
108          Nemanja Maksimovic           David Soria Solís      pass        42
110        Djené Dakonam Ortega           Jaime Mata Arnaiz      pass        43
112        Djené Dakonam Ortega  Mathías Olivera Miramontes      pass        44
116           Jaime Mata Arnaiz          Jorge Molina Vidal      pass        45
121        Djené Dakonam Ortega       Marc Cucurella Saseta      pass        46
122       Marc Cucurella Saseta          Jorge Molina Vidal      pass        47
124          Jorge Molina Vidal           Jaime Mata Arnaiz      pass        48
126           Jaime Mata Arnaiz       Marc Cucurella Saseta      pass        49
131          Jorge Molina Vidal          Nemanja Maksimovic      pass        50
```

Each row contains a player that passes to another player. Out of this df, I want to create a smaller frame of 20 rows (row 1:20, thus 20 passes) between players, and calculate network metrics, such as degree, betweenness, closeness centralities and clustering-coefficients.

After the metrics are calculated, the values should be saved in a dataframe (i.e. `temporal_network_AT` in the example).

I want to iterate this process, deleting the first pass and adding the 21st pass. The new window thus contains of rows 2:21. For these rows I want to calculate the network metrics again.

**This process has to iterate until the last pass is given (which is given in row 50 in the example).**

I have created the following for loop to try tackle the problem:

```
temporal_network_AT <- data.frame()

# Create the windows for the AT
  for(j in 1:nrow(pass_subset)){
    # 1: Grab first 20 passes starting from j
    passes_j <- pass_subset[j:20,]
    
    # 2: Calculate the metrics for this window
    gPass_AT <- graph_from_data_frame(passes_j)
    
    ## Individual stats
    
    # 2a: Clustering Coefficient
    clustCoeff <- igraph::transitivity(gPass_AT)
    
    # 2b: degree centrality
    degree <- igraph::centralization.degree(gPass_AT)$centralization
    
    # 2d: Betweenness Centrality
    betweenness <- igraph::betweenness(gPass_AT)
    
    # 2e: Closeness Centrality
    closeness <- igraph::closeness(gPass_AT)
    
    # 2f: Eigenvector centrality // page_rank
    
    eigenvector <- igraph::evcent(gPass_AT)$vector
    
    # 3: Store values in df
    temporal_network_AT <- as.data.frame(cbind(clustCoeff, degree, betweenness, closeness, eigenvector))
    
    setDT(temporal_network_AT, keep.rownames=TRUE)
    colnames(temporal_network_AT)[1] <- "Player"
    temporal_network_AT$passnetwork <- paste0(j, "_passes")

    j <- j + 1
    
  }

## Current Output:
                         Player transitivity    degree betweenness  closeness eigenvector passnetwork
 1:          Jorge Molina Vidal          0.5 0.3580247   28.800000 0.04545455  0.99930139   50_passes
 2:           Jaime Mata Arnaiz          0.5 0.3580247    7.183333 0.03703704  0.95503552   50_passes
 3:       Marc Cucurella Saseta          0.5 0.3580247    3.416667 0.03703704  1.00000000   50_passes
 4:        Djené Dakonam Ortega          0.5 0.3580247    0.000000 0.05882353  0.31609207   50_passes
 5:          Nemanja Maksimovic          0.5 0.3580247    8.500000 0.04166667  0.36036641   50_passes
 6: Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa          0.5 0.3580247   12.333333 0.04000000  0.36921736   50_passes
 7:            Oghenekaro Etebo          0.5 0.3580247    2.033333 0.03571429  0.27490330   50_passes
 8:  Mathías Olivera Miramontes          0.5 0.3580247    6.733333 0.04166667  0.59469541   50_passes
 9: Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi          0.5 0.3580247    0.000000 0.03571429  0.16441569   50_passes
10:           David Soria Solís          0.5 0.3580247    0.000000 0.01111111  0.08127063   50_passes
```

However, I get stuck in the actual iteration now. I only retrieve the output of the last pass (i.e. the 50th pass).

Thus what I would like is:

1. start with a df with rows 1:20,
2. calculate the parameters,
3. storing them in the existing dataframe `temporal_network_AT`,
4. a create a new frame with rows 2:21 etc.
5. recalculating the parameters,
6. append the new parameters in the existing dataframe 'temporal_network_AT'
7. create new frame with rows 3:22

repeat

Is there anyone that could help me?

## UPDATE

I managed to retrieve a list with all values, using the following code:

```
# Create the windows for the AT
for(j in 1:nrow(pass_subset)){ 
  
  # 1: Grab first 20 passes starting from j
  passes_j <- pass_subset[c(j, j+1, j+2, j+3, j+4, j+5, j+6, j+7, j+8, j+9, j+10,
                            j+11, j+12, j+13, j+14, j+15, j+16, j+17, j+18, j+19),]
  
  # 2: Calculate the metrics for this window
  gPass_AT <- graph_from_data_frame(passes_j)
  
  ## Individual stats
  
  # 2a: Clustering Coefficient
  clustCoeff <- igraph::transitivity(gPass_AT)
  
  # 2b: degree centrality
  degree <- igraph::centralization.degree(gPass_AT)$centralization
  
  # 2d: Betweenness Centrality
  betweenness <- igraph::betweenness(gPass_AT)
  
  # 2e: Closeness Centrality
  closeness <- igraph::closeness(gPass_AT)
  
  # 2f: Eigenvector centrality // page_rank
  
  eigenvector <- igraph::evcent(gPass_AT)$vector
  
  # 3: Store values in df
  temporal_network_AT <- as.data.frame(cbind(transitivity, degree, betweenness, closeness, eigenvector))
  
  setDT(temporal_network_AT, keep.rownames=TRUE)
  colnames(temporal_network_AT)[1] <- "Player"
  temporal_network_AT$passnetwork <- paste0(j, "_passes")
  
  datalist[[j]] <- temporal_network_AT
  
  j <- j + 1
    
}
 
big_data <- do.call(rbind, datalist)
```

However, the current list contains of 50 entries, while list should consist of 30 entries (1:20 passes until 30:50 passes). So the iteration should actually stop when the 50th pass is measured. What it now does is continuing like (31:50, 32:50, 33:50 etc).

Comment: The expected outcome would be a dataframe in which the same players are rbinded 30 times with the respective parameters and `passnetwork` increment (20_passes towards 50_passes)

Comment: I understand. It is actually a very complex problem.. I will try to rephrase

Comment: Oeps my bad, I changed `transitivity` to `clustCoeff`. I'll change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may serve your purpose to some extent.  However, there is some error at calculation of closeness(?) which needs to be taken care of.

```r
pass_subset <- structure(list(player_name = c("Nemanja Maksimovic", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", 
                                              "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Djené Dakonam Ortega", 
                                              "Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", 
                                              "Nemanja Maksimovic", "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
                                              "Djené Dakonam Ortega", "Nemanja Maksimovic", "Allan Romeo Nyom", 
                                              "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Allan Romeo Nyom", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", 
                                              "Oghenekaro Etebo", "Djené Dakonam Ortega", "Oghenekaro Etebo", 
                                              "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Mathías Olivera Miramontes", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
                                              "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
                                              "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Mathías Olivera Miramontes", "Mathías Olivera Miramontes", 
                                              "Nemanja Maksimovic", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi", 
                                              "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Mathías Olivera Miramontes", "Oghenekaro Etebo", 
                                              "Nemanja Maksimovic", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
                                              "Djené Dakonam Ortega", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Oghenekaro Etebo", 
                                              "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Nemanja Maksimovic", "Djené Dakonam Ortega", 
                                              "Djené Dakonam Ortega", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Djené Dakonam Ortega", 
                                              "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", 
                                              "Jorge Molina Vidal"), receive_player = c("Jaime Mata Arnaiz", 
                                                                                        "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", 
                                                                                        "David Soria Solís", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Nemanja Maksimovic", 
                                                                                        "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Jorge Molina Vidal", 
                                                                                        "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Jorge Molina Vidal", 
                                                                                        "Nemanja Maksimovic", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Oghenekaro Etebo", 
                                                                                        "Djené Dakonam Ortega", "David Soria Solís", "David Soria Solís", 
                                                                                        "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Jorge Molina Vidal", 
                                                                                        "Mathías Olivera Miramontes", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Jorge Molina Vidal", 
                                                                                        "Mathías Olivera Miramontes", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Nemanja Maksimovic", 
                                                                                        "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Jorge Molina Vidal", 
                                                                                        "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Oghenekaro Etebo", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", 
                                                                                        "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", 
                                                                                        "David Soria Solís", "Oghenekaro Etebo", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", 
                                                                                        "Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi", "David Soria Solís", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", 
                                                                                        "Mathías Olivera Miramontes", "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
                                                                                        "Jorge Molina Vidal", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
                                                                                        "Nemanja Maksimovic"), type_name = c("pass", "pass", "pass", 
                                                                                                                             "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
                                                                                                                             "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
                                                                                                                             "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
                                                                                                                             "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
                                                                                                                             "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
                                                                                                                             "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass"), no_passes = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50)), row.names = c(6L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                8L, 10L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 25L, 26L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                40L, 42L, 44L, 46L, 49L, 50L, 53L, 55L, 57L, 60L, 67L, 69L, 71L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                74L, 76L, 78L, 79L, 81L, 87L, 89L, 91L, 93L, 95L, 96L, 98L, 100L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                102L, 108L, 110L, 112L, 116L, 121L, 122L, 124L, 126L, 131L), class = "data.frame")

library(data.table)
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union
temporal_network_AT <- NULL
# Create the windows for the AT

for(j in seq_len(nrow(pass_subset)-20)){ 
  
  passes_j <- pass_subset[j:(j + 20),]
  
  # 2: Calculate the metrics for this window
  gPass_AT <- graph_from_data_frame(passes_j)
  
  ## Individual stats
  
  # 2a: Clustering Coefficient
  clustCoeff <- igraph::transitivity(gPass_AT)
  
  # 2b: degree centrality
  degree <- igraph::centralization.degree(gPass_AT)$centralization
  
  # 2d: Betweenness Centrality
  betweenness <- igraph::betweenness(gPass_AT)
  
  # 2e: Closeness Centrality
  closeness <- igraph::closeness(gPass_AT)
  
  # 2f: Eigenvector centrality // page_rank
  
  eigenvector <- igraph::evcent(gPass_AT)$vector
  
  # 3: Store values in df
  temp <- as.data.frame(cbind(clustCoeff, degree, betweenness, closeness, eigenvector))
  
  setDT(temp, keep.rownames=TRUE)
  colnames(temp)[1] <- "Player"
  temp$passnetwork <- paste0(j+19, "_passes")
  
  temporal_network_AT <- rbind(temporal_network_AT, temp)
  
  
}
#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

#> Warning in igraph::closeness(gPass_AT): At centrality.c:2784 :closeness
#> centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs

temporal_network_AT
#>                     Player clustCoeff    degree betweenness  closeness
#>   1:    Nemanja Maksimovic  0.3658537 0.2850000    3.000000 0.02000000
#>   2:     Jaime Mata Arnaiz  0.3658537 0.2850000    0.000000 0.01960784
#>   3: Marc Cucurella Saseta  0.3658537 0.2850000   14.000000 0.02000000
#>   4:    Jorge Molina Vidal  0.3658537 0.2850000   38.500000 0.02222222
#>   5:  Djené Dakonam Ortega  0.3658537 0.2850000    5.000000 0.02173913
#>  ---                                                                  
#> 307:    Nemanja Maksimovic  0.2926829 0.2345679    7.000000 0.02702703
#> 308:     Jaime Mata Arnaiz  0.2926829 0.2345679   14.666667 0.02857143
#> 309: Marc Cucurella Saseta  0.2926829 0.2345679    1.666667 0.02857143
#> 310:  Djené Dakonam Ortega  0.2926829 0.2345679    0.000000 0.05555556
#> 311:     David Soria Solís  0.2926829 0.2345679    0.000000 0.01111111
#>      eigenvector passnetwork
#>   1:   0.7648757   20_passes
#>   2:   0.7863909   20_passes
#>   3:   0.5759535   20_passes
#>   4:   1.0000000   20_passes
#>   5:   0.2738182   20_passes
#>  ---                        
#> 307:   0.3768013   49_passes
#> 308:   1.0000000   49_passes
#> 309:   0.8019546   49_passes
#> 310:   0.3970175   49_passes
#> 311:   0.1461630   49_passes
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Glad that it helped.  Fix your `closeness` calculation, and it may work completely as desired.  Please also consider an `upvote` if you think it really helped.